# Tag EBS Volumes at the time of EC2 Launch with the same tags as EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, terraform

I want to tag all volumes at the time of EC2 Launch itself in Terraform. The same EC2 Tags should be applied to its Volumes at the time of creation. I dont want to enter tags separately for volumes. The Tags of EC2 should be applied to volume automatically.

I know we can do it in aws console when doing it manually. But when creating with terraform, please help me can we do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code so far and explain exactly what's wrong with it that's not doing what you want?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I just wanted to know can we do it.. I can hardcore the volumes tags with values while launch. But I want to copy the EC2 Tags and put it in Volumes at the time of launch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [local values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) to store your tags and then use them with both `tags` and `volume_tags` like so

```terraform
locals {
  tags = {
    Name = "my-instance"
    Env  = "production"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "my-instance" {
  ...

  tags        = "${local.tags}"
  volume_tags = "${local.tags}"
}
```